# plotly is labeling my xaxis wrong. how to fix this?

Tags: python, plotly, pandas-groupby

in the image, you can see the final bar is Nov, but plotly is calling Oct Nov 2021. Why and how to fix?

```
orders_month = orders[['createdAt', 'order_total_usd']]
orders_month_grouped = orders_month.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='createdAt', axis=0, freq='M')).sum().reset_index()
orders_month_grouped['value_labels'] = orders_month_grouped['order_total_usd'].map('${:,.0f}'.format)
fig2 = px.bar(orders_month_grouped, x='createdAt', y="order_total_usd",   text='value_labels')
fig2.update_layout(
    title="Order Value by Month",
    xaxis_title="Month",
    yaxis_title="Order Value"
    )
fig2.update_yaxes(range=[350000, 600000])
fig2.show()
```

UPDATE:
found this workaround

seems I can fix it with this

```
    fig2.layout.xaxis.tick0 = orders_month_grouped['createdAt'].iloc[0]
    fig2.layout.xaxis.dtick = 'M1'
```

but why should I have to (why is it wrong)?

adding image of data
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you include some input data that illustrates the problem? Preferably `orders_month_grouped` which already grouped the data.

Comment: @Shaido added image to show the data

Comment: If you believe that your own fix sufficiently well answers your question, please create an answer to your own question and accept is as the correct answer so that it is masked as answered in the system.

Comment: sure but I still wonder why I need to manually correct this? Is it a bug in plotly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a fix: added xaxis_tick0...

```
fig2 = px.bar(orders_month_grouped, x='createdAt', y="order_total_usd",   text='value_labels')
fig2.update_layout(
    title="Order Value by Month",
    xaxis_title="Month",
    yaxis_title="Order Value",
    xaxis_tick0 = orders_month_grouped['createdAt'].iloc[0],
    xaxis_dtick = 'M1'
)
```